# how to pass the JSON data from the controller to AngularJS in asp.net mvc?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

i want to pass the json data from controller to angularjs..i have tried the below code but just only show the table header don't show my product data..below put my code..
 this is my angularjs code..

```
   $scope.ViewPro = function () {    
    $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'AddToCart/ProList' }).
    success(function (p) {
        debugger;            
        console.log(p);
        $scope.Products = p; // Response Data                 
        $location.path('/ViewProduct');
    }).
    error(function (data) {
        alert(data + "Error");
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

this is my json controller method..

```
  public JsonResult ProList()
    {
        var ProductList = db.tblProducts.ToList();
        var Products = ProductList.Select(d => new
        {
            d.ProductId,
            d.ProductName,
            d.Price,
            d.Descripation,
            d.SEOURL,
            d.Image,
            d.IsPubliesd,
        }).ToList();
        return Json(Products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

this is my routeProvider

```
.when('/ViewProduct', { templateUrl: 'AddToCart/ViewProduct' })
```

this is my view..

```
@model IEnumerable<AJSWithShoppingCart.Models.tblProduct>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AddToCart" ng-model="AddToCart"> 
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><b>ProductId</b></td>
                <td align="center"><b>ProductName</b></td>
                <td align="center"><b>Descripation</b></td>
                <td align="center"><b>Price</b></td>
                <td align="center"><b>SEOURL</b></td>
                <td align="center"><b>IsPubliesd</b></td>                    
                <td align="center"><b>AddToCart</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="Product in Products">
                <td ng-bind="Product.ProductId"></td>
                <td>{{Product.ProductName}}</td>
                <td>{{Product.Descripation}}</td>
                <td>${{Product.Price}}.00</td>
                <td>{{Product.SEOURL}}</td>
                <td>{{product.ispubliesd}}</td>                                      
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: After you fetched data you invoke `$location.path('/ViewProduct');` i.e. you loaded data under one controller and attempt to process it under another controller that is why data lossed. You can check it by assigning data to `$rootScope` and change view to use `$rootScope` too.

Comment: hello slava Utesinov please expain what is $rootScope and how to use in my demo project??

Comment: $rootScope - is a global scope that is available from any place. Just write: $rootScope.Products = p; instead $scope.Products = p and that is all.

Comment: hello  Slava Utesinov can i replace $scope to $rootScope???

Comment: thank you so much  Slava Utesinov.